# Is there dynamic type support?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

In MobX state tree, how can I define a property with a dynamic type? ex: can be assigned to any type.. like integer, string, boolean, object, etc

Any idea? Is defining type mandatory in MST ?

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this it's best to use a union

```
myModel = types.model({
  title: types.string,
  dynamicProperty: types.union(
    types.number,
    types.string,
    types.boolean,
    types.model({
      anotherProperty: types.string 
    }),
    testModel
  )
})

testModel = types.model({})
```

`dynamicProperty` can be either a string, number, a boolean or an instance of the model defined inside, or an instance of testModel.

More on union type in the API docs 
https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/master/docs/API/README.md#union